# devexpress master-detail change default columns in detail view

Tags: c#, devexpress

How can I change default columns (I mean remove some in details view ? in XtraGridView

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the designer, create a detail GridView and design its columns the way you want.

Or do you want to do it programmatically?

Comment: Where in designer I can do it? Im talking about default masterDetail in xtragridview

Answer (score 0):

Click Retrieve Details in the grid on your form.

You will then see a separate GridView for each detail level.
You can select these views and change their columns or properties.